# Java DataInputStream methods in C# BinaryReader

Tags: c#, java

1. what is the java DataInputStream readFully method equivalent in  C# BinaryReader?
2. What is the java DataInputStream mark and reset methods equivalent in C# BinaryReader or Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. see [BinaryReader.Read(byte[], int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms143295.aspx)
2. There is no object that have this behavior in .NET, you should implement it by yourself.